# How do I search the next element in a list of multiple dropdowns

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, dropdown

It is choosing the same dropdown element twice. Overriding the already selected Captain . How can I ensure that the next element chooses Wicket keeper and not the same one chosen earlier. There is no other way of finding the element but by name.

This is the code:

```
Select dropC = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("playerRole")));
dropC.selectByVisibleText("Captain");

Select dropW = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("playerRole")));
dropW.selectByVisibleText("Wicket Keeper");
```

This is the html code:
select ng-model="playerRole" name="playerRole" id="plr16" ng-change="selectPlayersRole(this)" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched">  Player Captain Wicket Keeper Captain / Wicket Keeper

There is a list of 11 dropdowns and I need to assign one of the dropdown as "captain" and the other as "wicketkeeper".

Comment: You can use `findElements` to find all matching elements. You can call the `find` methods on elements instead of the `driver` too, then the search will be limited to the DOM of that element. The `findElement` method will always find the **first** matching element according to its documentation.

Comment: To me your question is unclear. What exactly differs, are you trying to access different dropdowns with the same name? Can you please show us a snippet of your HTML?

Comment: Thanks, but please **edit** your question instead and include the code there, well formatted.

Comment: findelements wont work. In that case I will have to change it to list and then wont be able to select dropdown

Comment: Please add the HTML to your question like you did in the comment section before. And then address what people said in the comments. Especially explain the situation in more detail. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What differs, are you trying to access different dropdowns with the same name?

Answer (score 0):

Take 11 players in an array say **String[] players = {"captain", "Wicket Keeper", "Batsman", "Batsman", "Batsman", "Batsman" "Batsman", "Bowler", "Bowler", "Bowler", "Bowler"}** then write below code to select them

```
List<WebElement> playerLocators = driver.findElements(By.name("playerRole"));
int playerCounter = 0;
for(WebElement playerLocator : playerLocators ) {
new Select(playerLocator).selectByVisibleText(players[playerCounter++]);
}
```

All 11 players in drop downs will be selected respectively.

**Note**: if there are more than 11 drop downs with the locator **By.name("playerRole")**, code may fail due to an exception **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**